# retrieve data from database and count second row and show it in label

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

```
conn.Open();
int a, b, c;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 3 pnrnumber from pnrstatus1 where Status='waiting'", conn);
DataColumn dc;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
{
    dc = ds.Tables[0].Columns[i];
    for (int j = 0; ; j++)
    { 
    }
}
```

Select top 3 pnrnumber from pnrstatus1 where Status='regret'

I want to show show

- 1st row number in label1
- 2nd row value in label2
- 3rd row value in label3

For example:

```
label1==21
label2==22
label3==23
```

If it has values i.e pnr number in table

```
sno    pnrnumber
1       21
2       22
3       23
```

Comment: rahul...sab hum kar denge to tu kya karega

Comment: thanx bro for your reply but you could have landed me a helping hand instead of taunting. anyways the person who wanted to help has already commented below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of columns. And use the `using` statement on `IDisposable` objects.

```
conn.Open();
int a, b, c;
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 3 pnrnumber 
from pnrstatus1 where
 Status='waiting'", conn))
{


using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)){
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    if(ds.Tables.Count > 0 AND ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count = 3)
    {
      Label1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["pnrnumber"].ToString();
      Label2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[1]["pnrnumber"].ToString(); 
      Label3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[2]["pnrnumber"].ToString();  
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to access the Rows with `ds.Tables[0].Rows` this modification:

```
            label1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
            label2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[1][0].ToString();
            label3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[2][0].ToString();
```

I can't understand why you are trying to go throught the for to the columns, in this sentence:

```
select top 3 pnrnumber
```

You are getting only the column pnrnumber